# How to set custom page size with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have scanned some materials at 600 dpi, ~ 9.36x12.67 inches and prepared in PostScript (PS) format.

Now when I try to transform PS to PDF with Ghostscript (GS), I get clipped output, as I assume GS's default page size is set to A4. I found available templates for GS here: **[updated]** https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#appendix-paper-sizes-known-to-ghostscript but none matches closely to dimensions of my PS files, so:

Can I instruct GS to output custom size, and if so how?

`-sPAPERSIZE` instruction seem to accept only predefined templates name, as in linked documentation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the used page size with `-gNNNNxMMMM` where NNMN is the width in *pixels* at 720 dpi (720 pixels == 1 inch), and MMMM is the height in pixels at 720 dpi.

Or you can set the custom size in PostScript *points* (72 points == 1 inch) with `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=w -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=h`.

If I'm not wrong, *9.36 inch ≈= 674 points* and *12.67 inch ≈= 912 points*.

You'll also have to apply `-dPDFFitPage` in order to fit your input onto the page.

So you could use either

```
gs                          \
   -o output.pdf            \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite        \
   -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=674  \
   -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=912 \
   -dPDFFitPage             \
    input.ps
```

or

```
gs                   \
   -o output.pdf     \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -r600             \
   -g8112x7596       \
   -dPDFFitPage      \
    input.ps
```

Comment: I think you wanted to use `-r720` for 720 dpi. Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: I have an app that is using Ghostscriptsharp (C# implementation). It's just a .dll and doesn't have all the command line options (that I can find) for custom page sizes. Any idea on how to implement this in this  wrapper?

Comment: rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dMySwitch");

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r720 -g4308x6066 -dPDFFitPage -o out.pdf in.pdf`

The `4308x6066` is the number of pixels, the `-r720` is the number of pixels per inch.

So here we have 720dpi, so for instance fo 5 inches, this will be 3600 pixels.

Answer (score 3):

I am using GhostPDL 9.10 and although my paper size of 8.5x13 is listed at https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#appendix-paper-sizes-known-to-ghostscript as `flsa` the `-sPAPERSIZE=flsa` switch had no effect, the paper size remained Letter.

The correct units for the `-g5100x7800` switch matched my `-r600` (not `720`); `-g` works.

Comment: link is broken. fixed link: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Known_paper_sizes

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with my problem. A ps-file as iso-A4 was converted to Letter, while the top margin appears shifted upwards. Using -sPAPERSIZE=a4, - thanks to the link, I get correct pdf format

Answer (score 2):

I found that `gs` was clipping my output even though I had forced the page to the largest standard size, A0.

The reason turned out to be that the PostScript document sent to `gs` by `groff` / `grops` contained a `%%DocumentMedia` specification that was overriding Ghostscript's choice.

The solution was to give `groff` the command-line flag `-p-P48i,48i`.  The `-p` tells `groff` to pass the rest of the option to `grops`.  The `-P48i,48i` to `grops` sets the paper size to 48 inches by 48 inches.