# How can I get the page size (print it to stdout) with Ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Can I just get the page size with Ghostscript?

I am aware if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943281/using-ghostscript-to-get-page-size) answer, but can it be done straight on the command line somewhat like this:

```
gs -dNODISPLAY -q -c "some postscript" input_file.pdf
```

as I cannot guarantee that `pdf_info.ps` is available where the command is run.

Comment: your answer is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675371/how-to-set-custom-page-size-with-ghostscript -- make sure you break up the command for the ease of figuring out the actual command

Comment: That's about setting the page size - I need to get the page size; thanks for highlighting the ambiguity of the question

Comment: pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 3 input_file.pdf

Comment: http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

Comment: gswin32c ^
      -dNODISPLAY ^
      -q ^
      -sFile=input_file.pdf ^
      -dDumpMediaSizes ^